# You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type when using Angular and LitElement

Tags: javascript, angular, webpack, lit-element

My application is built with [angular](/questions/tagged/angular) 7.

To boost some productivity I'm using components that are based on [lit-element](/questions/tagged/lit-element), exactly there are based on [ing-bank/@lion](https://github.com/ing-bank/lion).

When running that I got an error

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/@lion/accordion/src/LionAccordion.js 204:40
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (204:40)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
|
|   __setupSlots() {
>     const invokerSlot = this.shadowRoot?.querySelector('slot[name=invoker]');
|     const handleSlotChange = () => {
|       this.__cleanStore();
```

As I assuming, there is a problem to include [es6](/questions/tagged/es6) web components into [angular](/questions/tagged/angular) application that is targeting [es5](/questions/tagged/es5)?

How to make it work?

Comment: How are you importing it?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the `object?.property` [optional chaining operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) is very recent and the `=>` [lambda operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) wasn't in ES5.

Both are now supported in every browser except IE11.

I'd recommend targeting a more recent JS version, but if you need to work on IE11 you'll need to apply a transform down to it as part of your build. Webpack *should* be able to do it, but you may need to add [`babel-loader`](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/babel-loader/) to downgrade your dependencies.